# L'uso del termine "pescaiolo"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

È corretto utilizzare il termine `pescaiolo` per raffigurare il pescatore?

Eg: `Mio padre fa il pescaiolo`.

Comment: L'hai sentito usare secondo questo significato? Il vocabolario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pescaiolo/) dice che indica un sistema di pesca o il pescivendolo.

Comment: @Benedetta L'ho visto usare da un compagno durante un esame di scuola.

Comment: A me è capitato spesso di sentire il termine "pesciaiolo", probabilmente è una variante dialettale... ma di solito ha una connotazione negativa (nel caso specifico è utilizzato per campanilismo verso un abitante di una città sul mare)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il termine sembra essere di origine ed uso toscani. Il De Mauro e altri dizionari  citano tra i significati quello di pescivendolo, probabilmente si tratta di un uso impreciso del termine trattandosi di una variante dialettale. Inoltre ci sono pescatori che vendono direttamente  al dettaglio il loro pesce al rientro dalla pesca per cui non sarebbe scorretto l'uso del termine  in questo contesto.

[Pescaiolo](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/pescaiolo):

> - 1. OB pescivendolo
> - 2. RE tosc., pescaia
> - 3. TS idraul. pozzetto che serve a ridurre la velocità dell’acqua di sgrondo negli acquedotti